# How to get Selected checkbox into database

Tags: laravel, checkbox, relation

I have a page for purchase order in that page i show data from table obat and i want to get selected checkbox using that data into table purchase order

This is my table obat

```
         <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px">
             <tbody>
                 <tr class="text-center">
                     <th>No</th>
                     <td>Kode Obat</td>
                     <td>Nama Obat</td>
                     <td>Harga</td>
                 </tr>
                 @foreach ($obat as $key =>$o)
                 <tr>
                     <th class="text-center">
                        @foreach ($po as $po)
                             <input type="checkbox" name="select" id="select">     
                        @endforeach
                    </th>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $o->kode_obat }}">
                    </td>   
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}">     
                    </td>   
                     <td>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $o->harga_obat }}">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 @endforeach  
             </tbody>
         </table>
```

The checkbox(select) is from table purchase order but it can't show. if i did't use foreach its show

Comment: I guess it's $o not $po in inner loop. The value you are using is not in undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass array also to check if it is in the array or not then you can this like below.

in your controller

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $odat=Odat::all();
        foreach($odat as $od)
        {
            $listod[]=$odat->select;
        }
        return view('yourbladefile',compact('roles','listod'));
    }
```

then in your view

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select" @if (in_array(yourpurchaseordernamefromdb, $listod))
        {{'checked'}} @endif>Selected</td>
```

personally i managed liked this. hope it helps